# Hide Page Elements From View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a blog set up with the usual articles and tags on the index page. The Tags section also shows up on the sign-in and sign-up pages which doesn't look great.

The tags are set up in their own column under _side.html.erb - is there a way to hide them from all other pages apart from the index page?

```
<h3>Blog Tags</h3>

<div id= "tags" >
<% cache('all_tags') do %>   
<% for tag in Tag.find(:all, :order => 'name') %>

<ul style="list-style-type: none">
  <li>
     <%= link_to "#{tag.name}", tag_path(tag) %>
  </li>
</ul>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you

```
render :partial => 'side'
```

from within your application.html.erb, then you could use another layout for the index page which then renders the partial while the standard layout would not.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work and my app is almost finished. Is there another way to achieve it? Home kind of 'hide' method?

Comment: Well it's actually not so much work, just copy your layout, make the modification to application.html.erb and point your specific controller to the new layout with *layout 'new_layout', :only => :index*